# iOS9 Multi-Line UITextView not displaying properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I have an app that was using `UITextViews` to display text (possibly multi-line), and was working correctly in iOS8. I turned off scrolling by declaring `self.scrollEnabled = false`. The `UITextView` would break words to new lines where needed and all seemed to be working!

However, when I ran the code on iOS9, the `UITextView` would only display 1 line of text always (no matter how many lines of text there were).

[image]

I realized when I removed the `self.scrollEnabled = false` line, the `UITextView` rendered correctly (showing all lines), but it was back to being scrollable obviously and this was not the intention.

[image]

What should I do to allow the `UITextView` to render multiple lines AND turn off scrolling? Has anybody seen this issue before or have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please check the same behaviour by decreasing font size of the textView? Just for testing

Comment: Just decrease the font size so two lines can be fit in IB. then it will work

Comment: I am building out the size of the UITextView programatically. However, if I increase the height by a few pixels (same concept as decreasing the font size), you are right, things work! Weird that the measurement function of `boundingRectWithSize` changed from iOS8 to iOS9 though. Ill have to throw in a line that corrects for this size difference :(

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `textContainerInset` of the textView

The code below creates a UITextView with multiple lines (you should also set constraints to the textview)

```
let titleTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.text = "something to say"
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
    return textView
}()
```